# Stone battle axe vs steel battle axe

Tags: osr, adnd-1e, weapons, damage

What damage is done by a stone battle axe as opposed to a normal steel battle axe?  Specifically the kind sometimes wielded by troglodytes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For weapons of different material but the same mass the damage is the same. The difference shows up in durability. Stone weapons need to be sharpened more often and are more prone to break. Both characteristics are not addressed in AD&D.

You could give a blanket negative modifier (like -1 or -2) against those wearing metal armor to represent this. This uses the idea behind the weapons vs AC chart. If players were wielding these you could have each weapon make a saving throw after each fight. If failed it would be considered a club doing 1d6 damage.

Answer (score 5):

A stone battle axe will do the same amount of damage as a regular battle axe (1d8/1d8) but it will have a different array of saving throws due to its material.

Answer (score 2):

DnD does not change damage due to material. Normally there is only a cost, weight, or damage vs X change, and sometimes to the chance to break it (or it save vs).

Answer (score 0):

As given in the description, trogs may have javelins, stone battle axe, stone morning star, or sword. All should inflict damage equal to the characters' versions (PH p37). Leader trogs should have +1 to damage and the females -1, tho both at the DM's option.